# Bash Script: How to redirect output of $? value to variable when previous command is executed successfully

Tags: redirection

```
#! /bin/bash

# test.bash is trying to redirect output of $? which can be either 0 or non zero to variable. But following script gives only blank output to flag variable. Can you assist how to redirect $? value to variable? Why is it showing blank?

#check for 5 digit argument
read -p "Enter 5 digit Account Number `echo $'\n> '`" accNum
echo $accNum | grep "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" > flag
echo $? > flag
echo "flag is $flag"
```

Following is my test.bash:

```
~$ bash test.bash 
Enter 5 digit Account Number 
> asdf
flag is 
~$ 
~$ bash test.bash 
Enter 5 digit Account Number 
> 11111
flag is 
~$
```

Comment: I think you're confusing redirection of a command's output to a file (`>`) with assignment of some value to a variable (`=`). What you're doing here is the former. Check for a file named `flag` in your working directory; it should contain the last command's exit status. The latter would be accomplished by `flag=$?`.

Comment: Thank you @nickie . flag=$? is working.

Comment: one thing i noticed is, there shouldn't be any space after "=" for example flag= $?  . It will give error because of space: 1: command not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to accomplish is this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check for 5 digit argument.
read -p "Enter 5 digit Account Number `echo $'\n> '`" accNum
echo $accNum | grep -q '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
flag=$?
echo "flag is $flag"
```

Notice:

- no redirection of output is necessary;
- the assignment to `flag`;
- the regular expression is in single quotes, not double, as it contains `$`; and
- `grep -q` suppresses the output if the regular expression matches.